# How could MH370 fly west when satellite pings went east?

Tags: mh370-incident

I have a question perhaps best demonstrated with this image:

[image: Malacca Flight Track]

Malaysia published two maps with the preliminary accident report which allege MH370 flew west from Penang to MEKAR (above Aceh Province) and then between 18:25 UTC and 19:41 UTC flew west into the Indian Ocean.

The problem is the Burst Offset Frequency chart published 24 March shows a frequency drop after 18:25 UTC signifying flight away from the satellite.

After MH370 allegedly emerged from the Straits and turned south the track which Malaysia's Preliminary Accident Report claims MH370 flew (based on their analysis of the BOF chart data) the track makes even less sense because the distances away from the satellite continue to increase.

[image: BOF track + Satellite position]

And this image shows the distance relationship with the satellite:

[image: Track displacement from satellite]

There are also other (non satellite) reasons to question the validity of the alleged track through the Straits of Malacca. First is the claim MH370 was seen flying west by radar at Surat Thani in Thailand. That radar has a published maximum range of 200nm. Kota Bharu is 240nm away from Surat Thani.

[image: Surat Thani radar radius 92nm & 140nm]

This is not the only reason to doubt the alleged MH370 flight though the Straits. Malaysia presented this image to Chinese relatives at the Lido hotel in Beijing on 21 March and told them it was a military radar image from Butterworth of MH370 in the Straits of Malacca. They said it crossed the island of Pelau Perak at 18:02 UTC and disappeared at 18:22 UTC.

[image: Lido Hotel image]

The image however omits other aircraft known to be present at the same time:

[image: UAE343 overlay]

Worst inconsistency of all however is this, the radar image does not even come from the Butterworth radar. The real military radar used by Butterworth is a Thales Raytheon GM400 which has a screen display like this:

[image: Thales Raytheon GM400]

I don't understand how so many supposedly intelligent "experts" and journalists have managed to be deceived for so long except to say people believe only what they want to believe and shut their eyes to the truth.

Australian, Malaysian, Japanese, New Zealand and Chinese taxpayers collectively forked out $90m wasted taxpayer dollars for a search at the end of this projected BOF track in April which turned up no result.

My question is how does this mutually incompatible information prove MH370 flew west through the Straits at all?

Comment: Could you possibly include the position of the satellite at 18:25 as well as the angle that it was pointed at.  It's hard to understand what you mean without knowing the location of the satellite and the angle it was at when the data was gathered.

Comment: Why do you say that the data is mutually incompatible? Why could MH370 not be flying away from the satellite *and* be flying west?

Comment: Jay the satellite distances actually reduce by 5 nautical miles yet the BOF chart has the satellite receding away at speed.

Comment: Articuno it is incompatible for the satellite handshakes to be moving apart when investigators claim MH370 was flying towards the satellite. I can't explain it any clearer than that.

Comment: @user2357 You say that the satellite pings "went east", but I don't see that in the chart. What is the vertical axis in the chart? East-west? Or is it distance from the satellite? Why couldn't the pings be getting farther from the satellite *and* MH370 be moving westward. I don't see the contradiction that you're claiming.

Comment: @Articuno: The vertical axis is Doppler shift, which is proportional to speed relative to the satellite. The satellite should be Inmarsat-3 F1 geostationary at 64.5° E, 0° N.

Comment: @JanHudec So deviations up and down in the vertical axis correspond to velocity changes, and not necessarily a change from westbound to eastbound or vice-versa?

Comment: @Articuno: They correspond to changes of velocity component toward the satellite. In the area of question it may mean change of speed when flying east or west, but has to mean change of direction when flying north or south. It may _also mean a change in altitude_, because the satellite is much more _above_ than _west_ of the point (geostationary orbit is ~36 thousand km, or over 19 thousand nautical miles, above Earth)

Comment: @JanHudec If you'd like to add any of that to my answer, I can make it community wiki.

Comment: Your maps are not oriented with North at top, you don't mention map projection, you don't seem to be using spherical trigonometry and you don't seem to take into account satellite altitude and motion. Can you provide details of the mathematical model you are using which gives results differing from the tracks published by the Malaysian Ministry of Transport?

Comment: @Articuno asks "Why couldn't the pings be getting farther from the satellite and MH370 be moving westward?"because the satellite's location is east of India. The image is taken from the satellite's vantage. For the period after 18:25UTC the BOF chart shows dramatic frequency reduction which equates to velocity away from INMARSAT. The track proposed by Malaysian investigators claims it flew west towards INMARSAT at this time. It is impossible for both claims to be true.

Comment: @Articuno asks: "So deviations up and down in the vertical axis correspond to velocity changes, and not necessarily a change from westbound to eastbound or vice-versa?" No the increase in frequency relates to signal compression caused by the doppler effect. Doppler compression can only occur if there is a net velocity towards the satellite and that equates to a flight in a net direction west, yet after take off the BOF chart shows frequency increase whilst radar tracked MH370 flying away from INMARSAT... It is fundementally wrong. It is not about the semantics of inclination angles.

Answer (score 7):

You have an error in one of your major premises.

You say "satellite pings went east".

That can't be derived from the data you have shown. [The chart is showing Doppler shift](http://theaviationist.com/2014/03/27/inmarsat-helps-finding-route/). A westbound aircraft that is decelerating, or simply decreasing its component of velocity toward the satellite (by, for example, turning slightly southbound) will result in a change in the Doppler shift.

Deviations up and down on that chart don't correspond to the *velocity* being east or westbound, but *accelerations* towards or away from the satellite.

Comment: Doppler shift is proportional to relative velocity, _not_ acceleration.

Comment: But *changes* in the doppler shift (relative velocity) would be caused by acceleration. That was what I was trying to say.

Comment: A Doppler shift is a reflection of signal compression (towards INMARSAT) or expansion (away from INMARSAT). Where the frequency is increasing there has to be a net closure of distance westwards.

Comment: @user2357 That is false. When the frequency is increasing there has only to be a net *acceleration* towards the satellite, not necessarily a closure of distance westwards.

Comment: @ Articuno thank you for defining the problem in your position. According to the BOF chart there is not a net acceleration between 18:25 UTC and 19:41 UTC, there is a net deceleration.

Comment: @user2357 Deceleration *is* acceleration. If you're heading west and slowing down, you're accelerating eastward. If you're heading east and slowing down, you're accelerating westward.

Comment: From 17:07 UTC the BOF chart shows net acceleration towards the satellite (via constant frequency increase) at a time when radar observation proves the target receded east until at least 17:22 UTC, therefore the BOF chart data is at odds with the known flight path up to 17:22 UTC. That is not a false premise.

Comment: The alleged MH370 track through the Straits of Malacca towards INMARSAT are not a "deceleration" but are flight towards the satellite.

Comment: The alleged flight south along the coast of Sumatra back towards the Southern Arc recede away from the satellite yet for the same period (from 19:41 UTC) the BOF chart shows acceleration towards INMARSAT. That is illogical.

Comment: Net acceleration west is not inconsistent with eastbound movement. You do not understand the relationship between acceleration and velocity.

Comment: @user2357 it is not illogical that movement away from inmarsat could happen at the same time as acceleration towards inmarsat. Again, you demonstrate lack of understanding of the relationship between velocity and acceleration.