# Why do MH370 Indian Ocean INMARSAT distances increase when they should decrease?

Tags: mh370-incident

This image illustrates my question:

[image: Satellite distance displacements]

In the Burst Offset Frequency chart from 19:41 UTC until the final ping at 00:11 UTC the blue track for MH370 shows increasing frequency, which means flying towards the satellite.

Therefore for the Burst Offset Frequency chart to be correct the flight track in maps released by the preliminary accident report should have curved west not east.

If they were fundamentally so wrong how could this ping chart ever have been used to plot the final location of MH370?

Comment: The "frequency offset" is a Doppler-effect-derived value.  It's related to the *speed* of the aircraft towards/away from the satellite, not its *distance*; the rising line is consistent with an aircraft slowly turning away from the satellite.  (It's also consistent with the aircraft performing a number of more improbable maneuvers, which is why the chart is simply the most likely track.)

Comment: If the BOF chart shows constantly increasing velocity towards the satellite, then the track distance should also reflect that. The problem is not my interpretation. The aircraft could not have flown the track suggested and give the offset frequency values reported. One or other is a lie and the lie is the official accident report's track which is a mere speculation.

Comment: @user2357 The problem *is* your interpretation. You assume that an increasing velocity towards the satellite means decreasing distance towards the satellite. That is false.

Comment: *"You assume that an increasing velocity towards the satellite means decreasing distance towards the satellite. That is false."* Why? If I run towards you with increasing velocity, my distance from you will decrease, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your question is based on a misinterpretation of the data, as already noted in [this aswer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3939/1467) to another (extremely similar) question you asked.

You say

> In the Burst Offset Frequency chart from 19:41 UTC until the final ping at 00:11 UTC the blue track for MH370 shows increasing frequency

That is a statement that contradicts itself.

The chart shows the *offset*, **not** the *frequency*, an increasing offset can mean both decreasing or increasing frequency, depending on the sign.

Most likely only the absolute value of the offset has been plotted for convinience.